# LEFT JOIN to newest row

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm trying to get data from one table with additional data from second, but in second table i have many records connected to records in first table and I want take newest.

In first table i keep products and i second i keep prices with data. I want take products with actual(newest) price.

Products table:

```
ID | NAME
---+----------
1  | "jacket"
2  | "pants"
```

Prices table:

```
ID | PRODUCT_ID | DATE       | PRICE
---+------------+------------+-------
1  | 1          | 2015-05-12 | 200
2  | 1          | 2015-07-12 | 100
3  | 2          | 2015-03-12 | 60
4  | 2          | 2015-08-12 | 90
```

Expected result:

```
1, "jacket", 100
2, "pants", 90
```

How can I do this?

Actually i've found solution - but with 2 subqueries. Doesn't look so good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the max date for each price and then inner join with the rest of the tables.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/423ab/3)

```
SELECT aa.id, aa.name, bb.price
FROM products AS aa
INNER JOIN prices AS bb
ON aa.id = bb.product_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM prices AS cc
    GROUP BY product_id
) AS _aa
ON aa.id = _aa.product_id
WHERE bb.date = _aa.max_date;
```

Comment: why join an additional select?

Comment: The ORDER BY is redundant